# Even value selection Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have 2 columns. The first has a list of odd and even number, the second is lets say a list of numbers ranging from 60 to 180. I already have a working formula — I think its called an array — that will search and pick the number closest to 100 from the second column.

Now what I want need is the search to select the closest number to 100 from the second column based on the corresponding column (row/line) to be an even number.  If for example it selects 104 and the number in column 1 is 11, it will then reselect the next closest number to 100 till it find the corresponding number to be an even one.  The corresponding number is not a fixed value and this is also variable based on other calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE1:**

*Noticed you want to use "INT()" so I have applied it in the formula below.*

---

I am not sure how you are doing your current formula, but here is an example how to get the number in column2 that is closest or equal to 100 and that has an even number to the left of it in column 1. I have added some fluff for proof of concept (like displaying cell address).

- Find out if a number is even by MOD 2 and see if it becomes 0 or not.
- Dump the columns into array for fast looping
- It's as simple as setting up several If then gates

```
Sub Test()

Dim col1 As Variant, col2 As Variant
Dim i As Long, max As Long
Dim maxCell As String

col1 = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
col2 = Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(col2, 1)
    If Len(col1(i, 1)) <> 0 And Int(col1(i, 1)) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        If col2(i, 1) <= 100 Then
            If col2(i, 1) > max Then
                max = col2(i, 1)
                maxCell = Cells(i, 1).Address
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Max: " & max & " found at cell " & maxCell

End Sub
```

Please note that if you have 2 occurances of the number closest (or equal) to 100 this will give you the first occurance. You can tweak it not to by simply changing `> max` to `>= max`

Comment: Thanks Adam.  This looks like what I am looking for.  I don't know how to actually apply this to what I have done. Can I send you the file?

Comment: I rewrote the functionality that searches Column B for the number closest or equal to 100, so you can omit that. Can you post some sample code in your question - maybe I can see where you might be having issues. BTW, if the answer works, you can click the arrow on the upper left to 'accept' it.

Comment: Column 1 I used =INT(A19) for all cells. I needed these from a previous calc to gove me a whole figure.  In column 2 I have figures that are calculated from 2 other columns...ie =F5*C5

Comment: Added in the INT so when you check for even/odd numbers you get the int-converted version of the cells in column A.

Comment: =INDEX(G5:G13,MATCH(MIN(ABS(G5:G13-A15)),ABS(G5:G13-A15),0))  This is the search formuula I used to search for the nearest value to 100.

Comment: Ditto on that code to be honest - I baked in my own checking in the answer though. It's really a matter of setting a 'closest thus far' variable and updating it as you loop and find cells closer.

Comment: Will try to absorb the above. With my limited excel knowledge it seems to make sense.

Comment: If this works, please accept the answer by clicking the arrow on the top left.

Comment: How do I connect the Macro above to the cell?

Comment: This is a sub - you'd have to rewrite it as a function and pass col1 and col2 to it as parameters

Comment: Thanks Adam...if I send you the file, do you think you can have a look at it?....I'm pretty desperate!!

Comment: I'll see if I can find some time - please send it ^^

Comment: Aha - no money needed but I hope I can help. Check my profile for my email a it's listed there. :)

Comment: sorry I can't see your email on your profile. Maybe I don't have access!